# log4j to filter out methods

Tags: java, log4j

I want to switch off the logging on a method of a class.
see below:

```
package com.mypackage;

public class A {
    public static void aaa() { 
        logger.info("hello"); 
    }

    public static void bbb() { 
        logger.info("hello"); 
    }
}
```

.

```
# This works and nothing gets logged by A
log4j.category.com.mypackage.A=off
```

.

```
#this does not work. (I am trying to switch off only the static method)
log4j.category.com.mypackage.A.aaa=off
```

Does anybody know if we can switch off (change log level) on a method basis ?

Thanks

Note: I don't want to change the code (that's because the code is already live I only want to change the existing log4j that's just a config file)

Comment: You are looking for aspect oriented programming. With log4j in its current state, you cannot do this.

Comment: hi Zo72 can you give me a simple example how to log this?

MyQuestion(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973901/how-to-log-my-java-program-flow-in-database)

Comment: @ameer too late... some other people already replied to your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a possibility to do this.

Nevertheless you can configure the logging to include the class and method name (see [PatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)) and postprocess the log file with other tools like '`grep`' to include / exclude what you want to see.

Due to performance issues it is not recommended to log the class and method names but maybe this is not relevant for you.

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is have two different loggers, one for each method.

```
private static final Logger logAAA = Logger.getLogger("some.logger.name.for.AAA");
private static final Logger logBBB = Logger.getLogger("some.other.name.for.BBB");
```

And then define different log levels for them in your configuration.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually possible by implementing a specific [`Filter`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html) that will check the logger name and then the calling method. Your filter receives a [`LoggingEvent`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LoggingEvent.html) which allows to retrieve the [`LocationInfo`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.html) with the class and method name.

Notice that this would use reflection on the stack trace which can be quite inefficient, do that with caution. In particular, first check the **logger name** before retrieving the `LocationInfo`, such that you only perform the reflection when necessary.

Configuring filters is only possible via the XML Log4j configuration file.

Quick implementation:

The filter class:

```
public class MethodBasedFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    public int decide(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (event.getLoggerName().equals(LoggingWithMethodFiltering.class.getCanonicalName())) {
            if (event.getLocationInformation().getMethodName().equals("filteredMethod")) {
                return Filter.DENY;
            }
        }
        return Filter.NEUTRAL;
    }
}
```

The filtered class:

```
public class LoggingWithMethodFiltering {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingWithMethodFiltering.class);

    public static void unfilteredMethod() {
        LOG.info("I am not filtered");
    }

    public static void filteredMethod() {
        LOG.info("I am filtered and will never appear");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        unfilteredMethod();
        filteredMethod();
    }
}
```

The `log4j.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>

    <appender name="Console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="threshold" value="trace" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p|%-20.20t|%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS}|%20.30c{1} %25.25F:%-4L - %20.20M - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter class="MethodBasedFilter" />
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="trace" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: if this can be achieved without code changes I am happy to use the XML log4j config file... can you please enrich your answer and explain

Comment: I added an implementation of the proposed solution. Of course you will have at least to add the filter implementation since there is no such filter out of the box. Depending on your environment you might need to put the filter in a jar next to the Log4j jar and not in the application itself to avoid class loading issues (e.g. if Log4j is provided by your application server)

Comment: @Zo72 indeed but I think it is the only solution to implement exactly what you want without post-processing the logs :) Nevertheless, you can put this class wherever you want as long as it is available in the classpath, which allows you to implement that without modifying your application. You could put it for example beside your `log4j.xml`. Alternatively, if you know the format of the messages that are logged within the method you want to filter, you could use a `StringMatchFilter` which is already provided by Log4j.