# how to log my java program flow in database?

Tags: java, events, logging, methods

I want to log what methods and what values are called in my java program in a text file or data base.

```
      For example:========================================

      this my java program


     Class A
      { 



        public void hello()

         {

           if(call.equalsto("world")
          {

           helloworld();
           }

            if(call.equalsto("boy")
          {

           helloboy();
           }

            if(call.equalsto("girl")
                        {

           hellogirl();
           }

           }


      public void helloworld()
           {


          system.out.println("hi world")
           }


        public void helloboy()
           {


          system.out.println("hi boy")
           }

                public void hellogirl()
           {


          system.out.println("hi girl")
           }

       }
```

So I call methods based on the input type. How to log which method is called and which value is printed as log in a text file or database?

Comment: by... using a logger? http://www.vogella.com/articles/Logging/article.html

Comment: @Najzero  I dont know which is best.But I try this. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any Java logger, take [log4j](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j) for example, its good documented and simple to use, take a look at [this example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm) and [this one](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/log4j/log4j-example.shtml).

You can download it [here.](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html)

There are several other logging tool for java, see a comparision on [this list](http://www.java-logging.com/comparison/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try log4j for all kind of logging use cases.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/